# Angular: How to get input value from nested ngFor loops?

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, input, ngfor, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to retrieve value from the following input field generated by a nested ngFor loop.

```
             <form>
                <mat-label *ngFor="let act of activity; let i = index;">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="actCheckbox">
                    <div *ngFor="let programSelected of programId; let index = index;">
                      <mat-form-field type="number">
                        <input matInput placeholder="No. of Applications" type="number" 
                          [(ngModel)]="formProfile.applications[programSelected]" 
                          [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" (blur)="recordApplication()">
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  {{func1Activities.activityName}}
                </mat-label>
              </form>
```

currently the input fields are generated vertically depending on the activities, and it is also generating horizontally depending on how many programs user selected.

`<input matInput placeholder="No. of Applications" type="number [(ngModel)]="formProfile.applications[programSelected]" >`

With this ngmodel, I was able to get the unique input value horizontally based on different programs, however, all the vertically input fields for each program seem to be bind together. If I input 1, that column of input fields all have a value of 1.

My question is how to locate individual input field and allow users to enter specific value into each input field?

Comment: Can you share a Stackblitz example?

Comment: Can you please try using this [(ngModel)]="formProfile.applications[index]" ?